# Arba'a Ve'arba'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred forty-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yitzhak's age when Yaakov got married.
(Yaakov was 77 when he got to Lavan. He worked 7 years, and then married Lea and Rachel, at age 84. Yitzhak was 60 when Yaakov was born, so he was 144 when Yaakov got married)

Comment: It's sad that he couldn't make it to the wedding.

Answer (score 3):

There are 144 Etzba'ot (fingers) in a Kane (קנה):
There are 4 Etzba'ot in a Tefach (טפח) and  6 Tefachim in an Amma (אמה), and 6 amot in a Kane

Answer (score 0):

8 x Chai

144 = Kedem

I guess it is a good reason to make a L'Chayim

Comment: gross! (pun intended)